# Invalidating reference tokens from code (not http call to revocation endpoint)

Tags: identityserver4

I am persisting reference tokens to a db, my users have the ability to change or get a generated password. But if for example a user have forgotten their password and gets a new generated one then i would like to invalidate/remove all current tokens for this subject. Is it a good idea/acceptable to interact directly with the db via efcore or is there a api for this besides the `/connect/revocation` endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in interacting with the database, but use the existing services to do this.

In IdentityService you can find the *stores* in the `IdentityServer4.Stores` namespace.

```
using IdentityServer4.Stores;
```

Inject the store in your controller:

```
private readonly IReferenceTokenStore _referenceTokenStore;

public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController(IReferenceTokenStore referenceTokenStore)
    {
        _referenceTokenStore = referenceTokenStore;
    }
}
```

And call it to remove the reference tokens for this user / client combination:

```
await _referenceTokenStore.RemoveReferenceTokensAsync(subjectId, clientId);
```

This will effectively remove the records from the database. You shouldn't create your own model of the database and remove the tokens directly.

Since IdentityServer is open source, you can take a [look at the code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/ResponseHandling/Default/TokenRevocationResponseGenerator.cs#L99) that is used for token revocation.